# Transform array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I transform this array

```
dataJson = [
 { name: 'Indicator1', date: '2022-01-31', data: 4.85 },
 { name: 'Indicator2', date: '2022-01-31', data: 6.00 },
 { name: 'Indicator3', date: '2022-01-31', data: 14.85 },
 { name: 'Indicator1', date: '2022-03-31', data: 10.50 },
 { name: 'Indicator2', date: '2022-03-31', data: 21.00 }
]
```

to this form

```
seriesData = [
 { name: 'Indicator1', data: [4.85, 10.50]},
 { name: 'Indicator2', data: [6.00, 21.00]},
 { name: 'Indicator3', data: [14.85]}
]
```

I suspect I can use dataJson.reduce() but I don't know how. Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to group based on `name` in an object accumulator.

```js
const dataJson = [ { name: 'Indicator1', date: '2022-01-31', data: 4.85 }, { name: 'Indicator2', date: '2022-01-31', data: 6.00 }, { name: 'Indicator3', date: '2022-01-31', data: 14.85 }, { name: 'Indicator1', date: '2022-03-31', data: 10.50 }, { name: 'Indicator2', date: '2022-03-31', data: 21.00 } ],
      result = Object.values(dataJson.reduce((r, {name, data}) => {
        r[name] ??= {name, data: []};
        r[name].data.push(data);
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```